# ArcGIS Network Analyst OD Cost Matrix - how to change network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, origin-destination

I am using Network Analyst OD Cost Matrix to calculate the distance between a number of locations in dataA and a number of locations in dataB.

I wonder how to change the network used for these calculations. The default under Network Analysis -> Network Data Source is arcgis.com. I assume that the Input Network Analysis Layer is where I choose along which network the distances should be calculated. By default, it says OD Cost Matrix.

I have my own road map that I would like to calculate the distances along, in shp-format. I have added this to my map, so I can see the roads. But I cannot figure out how to use this as th network in OD Cost Matrix calculations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all You should build network dataset, based on your roads. After this step You will be able to calculate OD matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! And a network dataset is possible to build from a road map in shp-format that I read in to ArcGIS?

Comment: You can do it from shape file. But for better result, your data must be topologicaly valid. Topology class can be built only in geodatabase. To build a ND, you need a Network Analyst license and a data in a specific format - you need a description for oneway roads, connections, turn restrictions. If You need only to create a simple geometric network, or walkaway-like network, you can create a ND with default parameters and 'any point' as a connection.